# I always get 0 when subtracting time

Tags: java

So I'm making an app that gets 2 time strings and subtracts them so I can get the amount of time that passed and for some reason, it always returns 0 please help me.

Here is the code I'm using

```
static String TimeIn() {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    Date time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    a = format.format(time);
    return a;
}

static String TimeOut() {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    Date time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    b = format.format(time);
    return b;
}

static long Duration() throws ParseException {
    String a = TimeIn();
    String b = TimeOut();
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    Date date1 = format.parse(a);
    Date date2 = format.parse(b);
    long dur = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    return dur / 1000;
}

static String a;
static String b;
```

Comment: And the values of `date2.getTime()` and `date1.getTime()` are within 1000ms of each other?

Comment: I make sure to press the time out button after a few seconds have passed so it should be. I also tried returning only the value of dur without dividing it by 1000 but it still returns 0

Comment: One really simple debugging technique is to print out the values. You'll no doubt find that the two times are within 1000ms of each other (they might even be identical), the subtraction yields a result that is less than 1000, and the division of that number by 1000 yields 0.

Comment: question: why convert to string, and then back to date? Just return and work with dates, only convert to string for output. Also consider that `hh` is used for hours 1-12, not 24. And, BTW, `Date`, `Calendar` are old and almost deprecated - use `java.time` instead

Answer (score 0):

Your code gets two times.

After that , you calculate the difference and divide it by 1000.

The problem is that the times are in milliseconds as `long` values.

The times may be calculated in less than a millisecond and may therefore be equal as `long` cannot store decimals.

Also the division by 1000 makes it worse as it erases all differences **that are smaller than a second**.

In other words, the time difference between the call of `TimeIn` and `TimeOut` has to be at least one second if the result should not be `0`.

[**Note**]

By convention, method names should start with a lowercase letter in java.

Answer (score 0):

You make one measurement immediately after the other.

Consider the following scenario:

```
String a = TimeIn();
Thread.sleep(2000L);
String b = TimeOut();
```

Then the output is: **2**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you call `TimeIn` right after `TimeOut`. These execute in under a second, so that your dates (that are only precise to the second) are the same. Putting a `Thread.sleep(100000)` in between prints the correct duration:

```
// throw Exception for brevity
 static long Duration() throws Exception{
    String a=TimeIn();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    String b=TimeOut();
    // ...
}
```

For more precise duration measurements use `System.currentTimeMillis()` or even `System.nanoTime()`:

```
long then = System.currentTimeMillis();

// do stuff

long duration = System.currentTimeMillis() - then;
```

This gives you the time in milliseconds. In this example, `Duration()` runs in 30-50 ms
Also, methods usually start with a small letter, like `duration()` or `timeIn()`.

Answer (score 0):

The time difference execution of the  TimeIn() and TimeOut() is negligible. We can use Thread.sleep();

```
class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println(Duration());
    }

    static String TimeIn() throws InterruptedException {
        SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss:SSS");
        Date time= Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        a=format.format(time);
        return a;
    }
    static String TimeOut(){
        SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss:SSS");
        Date time= Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        b=format.format(time);
        return b;
    }
    static long Duration() throws ParseException, InterruptedException {
        String a=TimeIn();
        String b=TimeOut();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss:SSS");
        Date date1 = format.parse(a);
        Date date2 = format.parse(b);
        long dur = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
        return dur/1000;
    }
    static String a;
    static String b;

}
```